# What does the devel flag do in kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThEsWl3sYtM) youtube tutorial and the instructor runs this command.

```sh
helm install --name istio incubator/istio --namespace istio-system --devel
helm upgrade istio incubator/istio --reuse-values --set istio.install=true --devel
```

What does the `--devel` flag do? I cant seem to find its reference?

Omitting the `--devel` flag gives this error

```sh
Error: failed to download "incubator/istio" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
helm install --help | grep devel

  --devel                    use development versions, too. Equivalent to version '>0.0.0-0'. If --version is set, this is ignored.
```

[HELM UPGRADE](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-upgrade) manual:

> This command upgrades a release to a specified version of a chart
>   and/or updates chart values.
>
> Required arguments are release and chart. The chart argument can be
>   one of: - a chart reference(‘stable/mariadb’); use ‘–version’ and
>   ‘–devel’ flags for versions other than latest, - a path to a chart
>   directory, - a packaged chart, - a fully qualified URL.